# Angular hide duplicate values of array

Tags: angular

Angular need to hide the duplicate value of array. someone answer me and its not showing duplicate but when im using filter to change value its showing old valus and also new values.

.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Policy</label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userFilter.policy_id">
      <option *ngFor="let policy of policy_id" value="{{policy}}">{{policy}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
getClaims() {
  if (this.userFilter.company_id) {
    this.url = 'url.com&company_id=' + this.userFilter.company_id;
    this.spinner.show();
  } else {
    this.url = 'url.com';
    this.spinner.show();
  }
  this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.data = data.records;
    this.data.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id));
  });
}
```

Also attach the image. One page its showing 2 values. and when im filtering data . its showing 2 previous value and one new value. I want only new values here.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you do anything that actually filters the data?

Comment: its just changing data on select the values in ngmodel.

Comment: Try `let uniqueArray = [...new Set(this.data.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id)))]; console.log(uniqueArray);`

Comment: TypeError: (intermediate value).slice is not a function . this error shows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding to your array, try replacing it.

```
getClaims() {
  if (this.userFilter.company_id) {
    this.url = 'url.com&company_id=' + this.userFilter.company_id;
    this.spinner.show();
  } else {
    this.url = 'url.com';
    this.spinner.show();
  }
  this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.data = data.records;
    this.policy_id = this.data.map(d => d.policy_id); // this changed
  });
}
```

Comment: its not hiding the duplicate arrays

Comment: Whats your console output of data and this.policy_id at the end of your http get subscribe?

Comment: i attach the screenshot of console in question

Comment: I don't see any other problems. If you posted all the code concerning this.policy_id in your question, the replacement code above should do the trick.

Comment: if im adding your line in array its show all the values its not hidig duplicate value.

Comment: im doing same as you say but its showing duplicates